# Is it legally allowed to fork a Codeplex project to a Github account?

Tags: github, licensing, codeplex

I've been thinking about creating a fork on GitHub of the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) project (which is hosted on Codeplex), but I don't know if I'm violating some legal rights.

Is it possible?

Comment: You have to read the license, or ask the author. Or better yet, ask a lawyer.

Comment: It's legally allowed to use it in commercial software and to modify it. http://www.tldrlegal.com/license/microsoft-public-license-%28ms-pl%29

Comment: Instead of starting with a lawyer, how about starting with the creator(s) of the project? Seems like reaching out would be the easiest way across the board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## DISCLAIMER

### I am no lawyer, this is more of a guess just based on observations from the license text.

They seem to use Microsoft Public License.

You are allowed to fork, host and change the code if you want.

You need to keep the same license.

You must keep the copyright. That means you can't just say that you wrote that software originally, you need to keep credit where credit is due.

Check the license for more information:

- http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/license
- http://www.tldrlegal.com/license/microsoft-public-license-%28ms-pl%29